# Making update in a specific row

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have an website you can [click it to see.](http://atageomatic.pythonanywhere.com/)
[image: General looking of my website]

It is real time excell sheet.So far I can delete a specific row but I couldn't find how can update a specific row which any user selects.

What should I do, actually I do not know the right question I need to ask to google. I can really accept  any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic route that takes the value from the id in the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('URL', id=id) }}">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

and in your routes:

```
@app.route("/id/<id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
```